# Select rows based on an index for uneven length

Tags: r, subset, panel-data

I'm working with a panel for various countries.
I need to select periods before and after an "episode".
The idea is that episodes have different durations, both, for different countries, and even within the same country: nor two episodes are equal.
I would like to select two years before and after each episode, taking into account the disparity in episode length.
Episodes are marked with the dummy "episode", which ==1 for any episode (and 0 otherwise). The duration of each episode is marked with the variable "length" and each episode has a unique id "epi_id"

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Benin", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Chile", "Cyprus", 
"Ecuador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Gabon", "Ghana", "Guatemala", 
"Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", "India", "Jordan", "Lebanon", "Liberia", 
"Madagascar", "Mali", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nepal", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Peru", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Uganda", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), date = structure(c(36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L), .Label = c("1965", 
"1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", 
"1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", 
"1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"), class = c("pseries", 
"factor")), oda_gdp = c(0.00156224191899326, 0.000988957098066082, 
0.0614124223405609, -0.00952598136225538, 0.0176037889265496, 
0.0196632943539649, 0.01516419302378, 0.0179255521876097, 0.0239838052961294, 
0.0339918427327225, 0.0434552651595577, 0.0245763751468202, 0.0294215254504361, 
0.0335777128393743, 0.0435315229046721, 0.0429014367766353, 0.0126736728805196, 
0.045408938716009, 0.0490745487739037, 0.171774646408361, 0.213582202051507, 
0.20962829598101, 0.159535485887771, 0.141480558568076, 0.122576467168789, 
0.0713821323019706, 0.0393622996447512, 0.229106174329137, 0.0675161693597474, 
0.0911053925351582, 0.093890717149679, 0.14423091075942, 0.155766338497113, 
0.128126701431687, 0.143644408542722, 0.104963836835233, 0.172437345497423, 
0.141892181378248, 0.191602995858257, 0.177812755764901, 0.225456222273764, 
0.291406658686742, 0.130123246461216, 0.249038950753005, 0.188346303735714, 
0.17925636981019, 0.141916056423704, 0.146904604324012, 0.152485757354407, 
0.120983465080552, 0.15408635384128), episode = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), length = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), epi_id = c(0, 0, 30, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 33, 0, 
34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -51L), groups = structure(list(
    country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
    23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
    26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
    29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
    31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
    34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
    36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 
    38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
    41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
    43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 
    45L, 45L, 45L), .Label = c("Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Benin", 
    "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Chile", "Cyprus", "Ecuador", "Equatorial Guinea", 
    "Gabon", "Ghana", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", 
    "India", "Jordan", "Lebanon", "Liberia", "Madagascar", "Mali", 
    "Mexico", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nepal", "Nicaragua", 
    "Niger", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
    "Peru", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
    "Singapore", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
    "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = c("pseries", "factor"
    )), potential_episode_grp = c(0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 
    0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 0L, 
    2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 
    6L, 8L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
    7L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 
    0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 
    4L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 
    10L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 
    3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 
    17L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
    8L, 10L, 12L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 0L, 2L, 
    4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
    7L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 
    16L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
    11L, 13L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 0L, 2L, 
    4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 0L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
    11L, 13L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 
    6L), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L), 3:5, 7L, 12L, 15L, 28:29, 33L, c(46L, 47L, 
    48L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
    62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
    77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L), 44:45, 50L, 55L, 70L, 75:76, 
        c(86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 95L, 96L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
        101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
        113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
        122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
        134L, 135L, 136L), 83:85, 89L, 93:94, 97L, 107:109, 126:128, 
        c(137L, 138L, 139L, 142L, 143L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
        149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
        163L, 165L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
        175L, 179L, 180L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 189L), 
        140:141, 144L, 154:157, 162L, 164L, 166:167, 176:178, 
        181:182, 188L, 190L, c(191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 
        196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 204L, 206L, 207L, 
        208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 
        217L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 
        230L, 231L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 
        241L, 242L, 243L, 244L), 202:203, 205L, 218:220, 229L, 
        232:233, c(248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 
        256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
        266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 
        275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 
        284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 
        293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L), 245:247, 255L, 265L, c(298L, 
        299L, 300L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 
        312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 
        321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 
        330L), 301:303, 307L, c(332L, 333L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 
        338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 346L, 347L, 
        348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 
        357L, 358L, 359L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 368L, 369L, 
        370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L), 331L, 334L, 
        345L, 360L, 365:367, c(377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 
        382L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 
        397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 
        406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L), 
        383:388, c(418L, 422L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 
        429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 
        440L, 442L, 443L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 453L, 
        454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 
        464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L), 415:417, 419:421, 423L, 
        434L, 439L, 441L, 444:446, 452L, 460L, c(473L, 474L, 
        475L, 476L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 
        486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 492L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
        498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 507L, 
        508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 518L, 
        519L, 520L), 469:472, 477L, 482L, 490:491, 493L, 506L, 
        512L, 517L, c(521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 
        528L, 529L, 530L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 
        539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 549L, 550L, 
        551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 
        560L, 561L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 571L, 
        572L, 573L, 574L), 531:532, 543:545, 562:564, c(578L, 
        579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 585L, 589L, 590L, 591L, 
        592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 600L, 601L, 
        602L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 609L, 610L, 611L, 612L, 613L), 
        575:577, 584L, 586:588, 599L, 603L, 607:608, c(615L, 
        616L, 617L, 618L, 619L, 621L, 622L, 624L, 625L, 626L, 
        627L, 628L, 629L, 630L, 631L, 634L, 635L, 636L, 637L, 
        638L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 
        648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 
        657L, 658L, 659L, 660L), 614L, 620L, 623L, 632:633, 639L, 
        c(661L, 662L, 663L, 664L, 665L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 
        670L, 671L, 672L, 673L, 674L, 675L, 676L, 677L, 678L, 
        679L, 682L, 683L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L, 
        691L, 692L, 693L, 694L, 695L, 698L, 699L, 700L, 701L, 
        702L, 703L), 680:681, 684L, 696:697, 704L, 705:758, c(763L, 
        764L, 767L, 768L, 769L, 770L, 771L, 772L, 773L, 774L, 
        775L, 778L, 779L, 780L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 785L, 
        786L, 787L, 788L, 790L, 791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 
        796L, 797L, 798L, 799L), 759:762, 765:766, 776:777, 789L, 
        800:804, c(805L, 806L, 807L, 808L, 809L, 810L, 811L, 
        812L, 814L, 818L, 819L, 820L, 821L, 822L, 823L, 826L, 
        827L, 828L, 829L, 830L, 831L, 832L, 833L, 834L, 835L, 
        836L, 837L, 838L, 839L, 840L, 844L, 845L, 846L, 847L, 
        848L, 849L, 850L, 852L, 853L), 813L, 815:817, 824:825, 
        841:843, 851L, c(854L, 855L, 856L, 857L, 858L, 859L, 
        860L, 861L, 862L, 863L, 864L, 865L, 866L, 869L, 870L, 
        871L, 872L, 873L, 874L, 875L, 876L, 877L, 878L, 879L, 
        882L, 884L, 885L, 886L, 887L, 889L, 890L, 891L), 867:868, 
        880:881, 883L, 888L, c(892L, 893L, 894L, 895L, 896L, 
        897L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 901L, 902L, 903L, 904L, 905L, 
        906L, 907L, 910L, 911L, 912L, 914L, 915L, 916L, 917L, 
        919L, 920L, 921L, 922L, 923L, 926L, 927L, 928L, 929L, 
        930L, 934L, 935L, 936L, 937L, 938L, 939L, 940L, 941L, 
        942L, 943L, 944L, 945L), 908:909, 913L, 918L, 924:925, 
        931:933, c(948L, 950L, 951L, 952L, 953L, 957L, 958L, 
        959L, 960L, 961L, 962L, 963L, 964L, 967L, 968L, 969L, 
        971L, 972L, 973L, 974L, 975L, 976L, 977L, 978L, 979L, 
        980L, 981L, 982L, 983L, 984L, 985L, 986L, 987L, 988L, 
        989L, 990L, 991L, 992L, 993L, 994L, 995L, 996L, 997L, 
        998L, 999L), 946:947, 949L, 954:956, 965:966, 970L, 1000:1053, 
        c(1056L, 1058L, 1059L, 1061L, 1062L, 1063L, 1065L, 1067L, 
        1068L, 1072L, 1073L, 1075L, 1076L, 1077L, 1078L, 1082L, 
        1083L, 1084L, 1085L, 1086L, 1087L, 1088L, 1089L, 1090L, 
        1091L, 1092L, 1093L, 1094L, 1095L, 1096L, 1097L, 1098L, 
        1099L, 1104L, 1105L, 1106L, 1107L), 1054:1055, 1057L, 
        1060L, 1064L, 1066L, 1069:1071, 1074L, 1079:1081, 1100:1103, 
        c(1108L, 1109L, 1110L, 1111L, 1112L, 1113L, 1114L, 1115L, 
        1116L, 1117L, 1118L, 1119L, 1122L, 1123L, 1124L, 1127L, 
        1128L, 1129L, 1130L, 1131L, 1132L, 1133L, 1134L, 1136L, 
        1137L, 1138L, 1139L, 1140L, 1141L, 1142L, 1143L, 1144L, 
        1145L, 1146L, 1147L, 1148L, 1149L, 1150L, 1151L), 1120:1121, 
        1125:1126, 1135L, c(1152L, 1153L, 1154L, 1155L, 1156L, 
        1157L, 1158L, 1160L, 1161L, 1166L, 1167L, 1168L, 1169L, 
        1170L, 1171L, 1172L, 1173L, 1174L, 1175L, 1176L, 1177L, 
        1178L, 1179L, 1180L, 1181L, 1182L, 1183L, 1184L, 1185L, 
        1186L, 1187L, 1188L, 1189L, 1190L, 1192L), 1159L, 1162:1165, 
        1191L, 1193:1194, c(1195L, 1196L, 1197L, 1198L, 1199L, 
        1200L, 1201L, 1202L, 1203L, 1204L, 1205L, 1206L, 1207L, 
        1208L, 1209L, 1211L, 1212L, 1213L, 1214L, 1215L, 1216L, 
        1217L, 1218L, 1219L, 1220L, 1223L, 1225L, 1227L, 1228L, 
        1229L, 1230L, 1232L, 1235L, 1236L, 1237L, 1238L, 1239L, 
        1240L, 1241L, 1242L, 1243L, 1244L, 1245L, 1246L, 1247L, 
        1248L), 1210L, 1221:1222, 1224L, 1226L, 1231L, 1233:1234, 
        c(1249L, 1250L, 1251L, 1252L, 1254L, 1255L, 1256L, 1257L, 
        1261L, 1262L, 1263L, 1264L, 1265L, 1266L, 1267L, 1268L, 
        1273L, 1274L, 1275L, 1276L, 1277L, 1279L, 1280L, 1281L, 
        1282L, 1283L, 1284L, 1285L, 1286L, 1289L, 1290L, 1291L, 
        1292L, 1293L, 1294L, 1295L, 1297L, 1298L, 1299L), 1253L, 
        1258:1260, 1269:1272, 1278L, 1287:1288, 1296L, 1300:1302, 
        c(1303L, 1304L, 1305L, 1306L, 1307L, 1309L, 1310L, 1311L, 
        1312L, 1313L, 1314L, 1315L, 1316L, 1317L, 1318L, 1319L, 
        1320L, 1321L, 1322L, 1323L, 1324L, 1325L, 1326L, 1327L, 
        1328L, 1330L, 1331L, 1332L, 1333L, 1334L, 1335L, 1336L, 
        1337L, 1338L, 1339L, 1340L, 1341L), 1308L, 1329L, c(1346L, 
        1348L, 1349L, 1350L, 1351L, 1352L, 1354L, 1355L, 1356L, 
        1357L, 1358L, 1359L, 1360L, 1361L, 1362L, 1363L, 1364L, 
        1365L, 1366L, 1367L, 1368L, 1369L, 1370L, 1371L, 1372L, 
        1373L, 1374L, 1375L, 1376L, 1377L, 1378L, 1379L, 1380L, 
        1381L, 1382L, 1383L, 1384L, 1385L, 1386L, 1387L, 1388L, 
        1389L, 1390L, 1391L, 1392L, 1393L, 1394L, 1395L), 1342:1345, 
        1347L, 1353L, c(1397L, 1398L, 1400L, 1401L, 1402L, 1403L, 
        1404L, 1405L, 1406L, 1408L, 1409L, 1410L, 1411L, 1412L, 
        1416L, 1417L, 1418L, 1419L, 1420L, 1421L, 1422L, 1423L, 
        1424L, 1425L, 1426L, 1427L, 1428L, 1429L, 1430L, 1431L, 
        1434L, 1435L, 1436L, 1437L, 1438L, 1439L, 1440L, 1441L
        ), 1396L, 1399L, 1407L, 1413:1415, 1432:1433, c(1447L, 
        1448L, 1449L, 1451L, 1452L, 1453L, 1454L, 1455L, 1457L, 
        1459L), 1442:1446, 1450L, 1456L, 1458L, c(1460L, 1461L, 
        1462L, 1463L, 1464L, 1465L, 1466L, 1467L, 1468L, 1469L, 
        1470L, 1471L, 1472L, 1473L, 1474L, 1475L, 1476L, 1477L, 
        1478L, 1479L, 1480L, 1481L, 1482L, 1483L, 1484L, 1485L, 
        1486L, 1487L, 1488L, 1489L, 1490L, 1491L, 1492L, 1493L, 
        1494L, 1495L, 1496L, 1497L, 1498L, 1499L, 1500L, 1501L, 
        1502L, 1503L, 1505L, 1506L, 1507L, 1508L, 1509L, 1510L, 
        1511L, 1512L, 1513L), 1504L, c(1514L, 1515L, 1516L, 1517L, 
        1518L, 1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 1523L, 1524L, 1525L, 1526L, 
        1527L, 1528L, 1529L, 1530L, 1531L, 1532L, 1533L, 1534L, 
        1535L, 1536L, 1537L, 1538L, 1539L, 1540L, 1543L, 1544L, 
        1545L, 1546L, 1547L, 1548L, 1549L, 1550L, 1551L, 1552L, 
        1553L, 1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1557L, 1558L, 1559L, 1560L, 
        1561L, 1562L, 1563L, 1564L, 1565L), 1522L, 1541:1542, 
        c(1566L, 1567L, 1568L, 1569L, 1571L, 1572L, 1573L, 1574L, 
        1576L, 1577L, 1578L, 1579L, 1581L, 1583L, 1584L, 1585L, 
        1586L, 1589L, 1592L, 1593L, 1594L, 1595L, 1596L, 1597L, 
        1598L, 1599L, 1600L, 1601L, 1602L, 1603L, 1604L, 1606L, 
        1608L, 1609L, 1610L, 1611L, 1612L, 1613L, 1614L, 1615L, 
        1616L, 1617L, 1618L, 1619L), 1570L, 1575L, 1580L, 1582L, 
        1587:1588, 1590:1591, 1605L, 1607L, c(1623L, 1624L, 1627L, 
        1628L, 1629L, 1631L, 1632L, 1633L, 1634L, 1635L, 1636L, 
        1637L, 1639L, 1640L, 1641L, 1643L, 1644L, 1645L, 1646L, 
        1647L, 1648L, 1649L, 1651L, 1652L, 1653L, 1654L, 1655L, 
        1656L, 1657L), 1620:1622, 1625:1626, 1630L, 1638L, 1642L, 
        1650L, c(1660L, 1661L, 1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 1666L, 
        1667L, 1668L, 1669L, 1670L, 1671L, 1672L, 1674L, 1677L, 
        1678L, 1679L, 1680L, 1681L, 1682L, 1683L, 1684L, 1685L, 
        1686L, 1688L, 1689L, 1690L, 1691L, 1692L, 1696L, 1697L, 
        1698L, 1699L, 1701L, 1702L, 1703L, 1704L, 1705L, 1706L, 
        1711L), 1658:1659, 1673L, 1675:1676, 1687L, 1693:1695, 
        1700L, 1707:1710, c(1712L, 1713L, 1714L, 1715L, 1716L, 
        1720L, 1721L, 1722L, 1723L, 1724L, 1725L, 1726L, 1727L, 
        1728L, 1729L, 1730L, 1731L, 1732L, 1733L, 1734L, 1735L, 
        1737L, 1738L, 1739L, 1740L, 1741L, 1742L), 1717:1719, 
        1736L, c(1743L, 1748L, 1749L, 1750L, 1751L, 1752L, 1753L, 
        1754L, 1755L, 1757L, 1759L, 1760L, 1764L, 1765L, 1766L, 
        1767L, 1768L, 1770L, 1771L, 1772L, 1773L, 1774L, 1775L, 
        1776L, 1777L, 1778L, 1779L, 1780L, 1781L, 1782L, 1785L, 
        1786L, 1787L, 1788L, 1789L, 1790L, 1791L, 1792L, 1793L, 
        1794L, 1795L, 1796L), 1744:1747, 1756L, 1758L, 1761:1763, 
        1769L, 1783:1784, c(1797L, 1798L, 1801L, 1802L, 1803L, 
        1805L, 1806L, 1807L, 1809L, 1811L, 1812L, 1813L, 1814L, 
        1815L, 1816L, 1817L, 1818L, 1819L, 1820L, 1821L, 1822L, 
        1823L, 1824L, 1825L, 1826L, 1827L, 1828L, 1829L, 1831L, 
        1832L, 1833L, 1834L, 1835L), 1799:1800, 1804L, 1808L, 
        1810L, 1830L, c(1838L, 1839L, 1840L, 1841L, 1842L, 1843L, 
        1844L, 1845L, 1846L, 1850L, 1851L, 1852L, 1855L, 1857L, 
        1859L, 1861L, 1863L, 1864L, 1865L, 1866L, 1867L, 1868L, 
        1869L, 1870L, 1871L, 1872L, 1873L, 1874L, 1875L, 1876L, 
        1877L, 1882L, 1883L, 1884L, 1885L, 1886L, 1887L, 1888L
        ), 1836:1837, 1847:1849, 1853:1854, 1856L, 1858L, 1860L, 
        1862L, 1878:1881, c(1892L, 1895L, 1896L, 1897L, 1898L, 
        1899L, 1900L, 1903L, 1904L, 1905L, 1906L, 1907L, 1908L, 
        1909L, 1910L, 1911L, 1912L, 1913L, 1914L, 1917L, 1918L, 
        1919L, 1920L, 1921L, 1922L, 1923L, 1924L, 1926L, 1927L, 
        1928L, 1929L, 1930L, 1931L, 1932L, 1933L, 1934L, 1935L, 
        1936L, 1937L, 1938L, 1939L, 1940L, 1941L, 1942L), 1889:1891, 
        1893:1894, 1901:1902, 1915:1916, 1925L, c(1946L, 1947L, 
        1948L, 1949L, 1950L, 1951L, 1952L, 1953L, 1954L, 1955L, 
        1956L, 1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 1966L, 
        1967L, 1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 
        1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 
        1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
        1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L), 1943:1945, 1957:1959, 1968:1969, 
        c(2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
        2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2025L, 
        2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2030L, 2031L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 
        2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 2040L, 2042L, 2043L, 2044L, 2045L, 
        2046L, 2047L, 2048L, 2049L, 2050L), 1997:2003, 2012:2013, 
        2021:2024, 2029L, 2032L, 2039L, 2041L, c(2051L, 2052L, 
        2055L, 2056L, 2057L, 2058L, 2059L, 2060L, 2061L, 2062L, 
        2063L, 2064L, 2067L, 2068L, 2069L, 2070L, 2071L, 2073L, 
        2074L, 2075L, 2076L, 2080L, 2082L, 2083L, 2084L, 2085L, 
        2087L, 2088L, 2089L, 2093L, 2094L, 2095L, 2096L, 2097L, 
        2098L, 2099L, 2100L, 2101L, 2102L, 2103L, 2104L), 2053:2054, 
        2065:2066, 2072L, 2077:2079, 2081L, 2086L, 2090:2092, 
        c(2105L, 2106L, 2111L, 2112L, 2113L, 2114L, 2115L, 2116L, 
        2120L, 2121L, 2122L, 2123L, 2124L, 2125L, 2126L, 2127L, 
        2128L, 2129L, 2130L, 2131L), 2107:2110, 2117:2119, 2132:2133), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -260L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001c7e3f91ef0>)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It'd be great if you can provide an example of your desired output

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please set out what have you tried so far and why has it failed? Please include the code you have tried so the coding problem is made explicit.

Comment: Due to space reasons (I'm only allowd to post 30K characters...) I can't post my desired output, but the idea would be to have another dataframe where I get two years before the episode, the episode and two years after the episode

My intuition was to use dplyr's group_by(epi_id)
But I haven't figured a way to go much further

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.